# Google map api "directions" returned HTTP response code: 400

Tags: java, google-maps, grails, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get result for directions API of Google using `webservices` in **java/grails**, but getting error

> IOException occurred when processing request: Server returned HTTP
>   response code: 400 for URL:
>   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Anand
>   Nagar, Shri Krupa Society, Old Sangvi, Pimpri-Chinchwad, Maharashtra
>   411027&destination=Unnamed Road, Bopkhel, Pune, Maharashtra 411031,
>   India. Stacktrace follows: Message: Server returned HTTP response
>   code: 400 for URL:
>   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Anand
>   Nagar, Shri Krupa Society, Old Sangvi, Pimpri-Chinchwad, Maharashtra
>   411027&destination=Unnamed Road, Bopkhel, Pune, Maharashtra 411031,
>   India

Please tell if I am missing something

Note: Same URL works good if directly used in browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to HTML Encode the String. If you form the Raw URL string, as you are doing now, then there's space between Anand and Nagar and so on, which is not allowed.

Example - Do a google search on any topic and notice the space is replaced with + or %20 in URL.

Even when you paste the same URL in browser, it works. But notice the URL, the space should get changed to + or %20. That's because our browser application does the URL Encoding for us.

Refer http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp